# Javascript: Partially overwrite a function without overwriting a few lines of codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

Straight to the point.
I have a function in a javascript class E.G

```
export default class gf{
    iLoveThis(){
        this.state.MakeMeWhole = true;
        callBoyfriend();
    }
}
```

And What Im doing is essentially overwriting the method in another JS file. Like so **Note that I am extending the class into my other component class**

```
iLoveThis(){
    alert('Got Laid!');
    cheatOnBoyfriend();
}
```

Is there any possible way for me to overwrite that method in another class without losing the this.state.MakeMeWhole line? The callBoyfriend call and other parts will be overwritten. 
Assumptions to make is that I have implemented ILoveThis in many different different classes and so I prefer not to have to add additional codes in all the other classes but to modify the original method to accomplish this.

Couldn't find any viable examples to accomplish this as most examples told me to save the method, overwrite it then re run it after overwriting the method and that would lead me to modifying 100's of classes...

**Update**
What Needs to be done is

```
class Love {
  constructor(){
  this.state = 'love'
  }

  iLoveThis() {
  this.state = 'derp'
  callBoyfriend();
  }
}

class Love2 extends Love{
  iLoveThis() {
  cheatBoyfriend();//assume method exist
  console.log(this.state) // Somehow make this state as derp, means the codes in the original function are partially overwritten 
  }
}
```

Credits for the codes belong to the guy who posted a response at the bottom of the page.
Is this possible?

Comment: "*I have implemented ILoveThis in many different different classes*" - then you will need to separately overwrite it in many different classes, there's no way around that. Of course you could have avoided that with a better design in the first place. And you can do it programmatically, no need to touch 100 files.

Comment: *"I have implemented ILoveThis in many different different classes"* - Do you mean that the other classes have references to the original method, or that you have copied the source code shown into those other classes?

Comment: @nnnnnn I extended the original class into my new subclass

Comment: If you extend the class that's no problem, you only have to overwrite the method in the superclass just like all the examples you found told you to. Try it! And post the code of your attempt when it doesn't work.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: @Bergi, there is a reason for why I've used "could" and "evil" in a single sentence.

Comment: @Bergi, good question, to which I don't have an answer, so I'll remove my initial proposition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's what you want but try to use `extends`

Code :

```
class Love {
  constructor(){
    this.state = 'love'
  }
  iLoveThis() {
    this.state = 'derp'
  }
}

class Love2 extends Love{
 iLoveThis() {
    console.log(this.state) // love
  }
}

const l = new Love2().iLoveThis()
```

[Demo](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Creact%2Cstage-0&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=class%20Love%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor()%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.state%20%3D%20'love'%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20iLoveThis()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.state%20%3D%20'derp'%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Love2%20extends%20Love%7B%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20super()%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20iLoveThis()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(this.state)%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20l%20%3D%20new%20Love2().iLoveThis())

Edit: There is another example. You need to share a state object between your classes. First, `import` the `shareState` object inside your two files which contain each class. Now if you set the state, it will be updated and sharable.

`import shareState from './src/shareState.js'`

[Updated](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Creact%2Cstage-0&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=const%20shareState%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%20%2F%2F%20import%20shareState%20from%20'.%2Fsrc%2FshareState.js'%0A%0Aclass%20Love1%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor()%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.state%20%3D%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20iLoveThis()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20shareState.potatoes%20%3D%20true%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Love2%20extends%20Love1%7B%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20super()%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20iLoveThis()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20shareState.potatoes%20%3D%20false%0A%20%20%20%20shareState.tomatoes%20%3D%20true%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Anew%20Love1().iLoveThis()%3B%20%2F%2F%20call%0Anew%20Love2().iLoveThis()%3B%20%2F%2F%20call%0A%0Aconsole.log('state'%2CshareState)%20%2F%2F%20)

Comment: You can omit the constructor in the subclass.

Comment: Yours is something close to what i want but instead of overwriting this.state i want to overwrite different parts of the state. For example i have a line inside ILoveThis() that sets a certain property 'potatoes' as true. And when i ovewrite it i want to set another property 'chicken' as false but still want the property 'potatoes' to be set as true. Think this is achievable?

Comment: @INeedInsecticideToKillBugs Just call `super.iLoveThis()`?

Comment: You need a `state` object who you can share between your classes. View my example on my update code.

Comment: Allow me to slightly rephrase the question um, say the function ILoveThis() makes a call to another function after setting the state, all that I need is for the this.state line to remain while the other parts of the function be overwritten, is it possible? hmm maybe i should update my main question too...